# Multiple injection with Ninject: Named binding or WithConstructorArgument doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5, with C#, .NET Framework 4.7 and Ninject 3.2.2.0.

I'm trying to use multiple binding but I don't know how to do it:

```
container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<TRZFDbContext>().InRequestScope();
container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<ERPDbContext>().InRequestScope().Named("ERP");
```

I'm trying named binding.

I use `IUnitOfWork` as parameter of `GenericRepository` constructor:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    private DbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _context = (DbContext)unitOfWork;
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    [ ... ]

}
```

And I have bindings that they are going to use `ERPDbContext` or `TRZFDbContext`:

```
container.Bind<IGenericRepository<ProductGTINs>>().To<GenericRepository<ProductGTINs>>();

// ERP
container.Bind<IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW>>().To<GenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW>>();
```

The first one use `TRZFDbContext` and the second one use `ERPDbContext`.

In the following controller:

```
public class ERPController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW> ordViewRepository;

    public ERPController(IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW> ordViewRepository)
    {
        this.ordViewRepository = ordViewRepository;
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error activating IUnitOfWork
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
  1) binding from IUnitOfWork to TRZFDbContext
  2) binding from IUnitOfWork to ERPDbContext
Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency IUnitOfWork into parameter unitOfWork of constructor of type GenericRepository{IC_ORD_VIEW}
  2) Injection of dependency IGenericRepository{IC_ORD_VIEW} into parameter ordViewRepository of constructor of type ERPController
  1) Request for ERPController
```

But if I change the constructor:

```
public class ERPController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW> ordViewRepository;

    public ERPController([Named("ERP")]IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW> ordViewRepository)
    {
        this.ordViewRepository = ordViewRepository;
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error activating IGenericRepository{IC_ORD_VIEW}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IGenericRepository{IC_ORD_VIEW} into parameter ordViewRepository of constructor of type ERPController
  1) Request for ERPController

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IGenericRepository{IC_ORD_VIEW}.
  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

How can I set which bind must it use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example fails because you are adding `[Named("ERP")]` to an `IGenericRepository` argument but the named binding is for an `IUnitOfWork`, so it doesn't find any matching binding.

Instead of using named bindings you could provide the constructor argument in your `IGenericRepository` bindings, for example:

```
container.Bind<IGenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW>>()
    .To<GenericRepository<IC_ORD_VIEW>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("ordViewRepository", context => new ERPDbContext());
```

Comment: I have used `.WithConstructorArgument("unitOfWork", new ERPDbContext())`.